# pointer confusion with malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a working implementation of my code with a ton of mallocs. It has

```
struct* node myList;
struct node { ... } // contains stuff
struct* node_constructor(...) {
    node* tempnode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* next = ...;
    ... // some other info
}
```

and then in my main function I call

```
myList = node_constructor(myList,otherarguments...);
```

I'm thinking there's probably a way to do something like

```
temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node)*numberOfNodes);
for(i=0; i<numberOfNodes;i++) { temp[i].next = temp[i-1]; ... } // wrong?
temp[numberOfNodes-1]; // set myList equal to the last one
```

and get rid constructor function and all those individual mallocs, I just seem to be getting confused with what to do with my malloced space. So `temp` is a (node*), so I'm pretty sure my `temp[i].next = temp[i-1]` thing is wrong...and maybe some of the other ideas are too. If anyone has any advice/input, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Read up on "memory pools."

Comment: Please don't cast the return of `malloc` on the right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: This is not even close to legal C code.

Comment: thanks, n.m., but I do realize that =P

Comment: @Hanmyo: In which case, please read the help section of this site, specifically the bit on _"how to ask"_. It does ask for a minimal, _valid_ code example to reproduce the problem. And of course, _don't cast the return of `malloc`. Ever, unless you're writing C++_

Comment: @Hanmyo: Just noticed: `temp[i].next = temp[i-1]` is of course dead-wrong. The first time your loop gets executed, `i` == 0, and you're assigning `temp[0-1]` to `temp[0].next`. A negative offset is invalid/out of range in your code.

Comment: I knew this question would bring out the malloc() fanatics.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Sure, you could do that, kinda. As long as temp is big enough and you know that size beforehand. And `temp` would more likely be a `void*` or some generic container just to hang onto unspecified memory rather than node. (Because it's not a node, it's where all your nodes go. `temp[x]` when `temp` is malloced is kind of a hack).

But now you want to add another node to your list. How do you do that?

The individual mallocs let you add a single item to the list. And if you are in a situation where you want to add a number of items to your list, then you can just call the individual functions multiple times.

The idea of allocating a large pool of memory, and divvying it up into the piecemeal sections later is a valid idea and it has some performance benefits, but it's of limited niche use.

Allocating just enough memory for one more item is a lot more handy and common. You're not wrong, but trust me, learn how to do it the normal way first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to back your list with an array there is no need to have next pointers - the next object is the next index in the array.

There are both advantages and disadvantages with an array list implementation compared to a linked list implementation.

Comment: In my current (previous) version, I would free nodes and malloc new ones, I just wanted a good way to initialize the whole list. But I guess maybe if I only call malloc once I can't free parts of it? I think I'm maybe too confused about what I want for this to be a good question even. =P

Comment: You understand why you can't mix them, so you aren't that confused. At this point you shouldn't worry about the cost of a few mallocs. Just make sure you design solid helper functions for the basic operations (list_insert, list_remove).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a node like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
  struct node* next;
  struct node* prev; // optional for double-linked list

  uint8_t* data;
  size_t   data_size;

} node_t;
```

and then create it as

```
result_t  list_add (const void* data, size_t size)
{
  if(list_is_full()) // if applicable
  {
    return list_is_full_error;
  }

  node_t* new_node = node_constructor(data, size);

  if(new_node == NULL)
  {
    return memory_error;
  }

  list_add(new_node);

  return ok;
}

static node_t* node_constructor (const void* data, size_t size)
{
  node_t* new_node = malloc(*new_node);
  if(new_node == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  new_node->data = malloc(size);
  if(new_node->data == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  new_node->size = size;
  memcpy(new_node->data, data, size);

  return new_node;
}

static void list_insert (node_t* new_node)
{
  // add the node to the linked list here
  // set next/prev pointers of the new node and of adjacent nodes
  // increase node counter (linked list size) if applicable
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it looks to me like this is basically the version I already had where you malloc every time you create a new node?

Comment: @Hanmyo The difference is that this code doesn't mix up the linked list logic with the node allocation. A linked list serves two purposes: it enables fast addition/deletion of data in the list, and it also allows the program to save memory by growing dynamically. If saving memory is of no interest to you, but you are only interested in fast addition/deletion, then yeah, you can allocate some kind of "memory pool" instead.

Comment: @Hanmyo What you need to do isn't obvious in the question. As usual in programming, you have to define what problem you are trying to solve, before starting to solve it. Why are you using a linked list in the first place?